# How to load CartoDb using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cartodb

When I try to require the CartoDb library it returns a script error and then tries to load it direct from the server.

```
Error: Script error for "cartodb", needed by: app
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

I've created a simple example here:
https://github.com/JohnGale87/requirejs-cartodb-helloworld

Steps to replicate the issue:

1) Visit this page: https://rawgit.com/JohnGale87/requirejs-cartodb-helloworld/master/index.html

2) Open the console

3) See the error

4) View the network tab and see a 404 error where cartodb.js was attempted to be loaded (even though it is already compiled into app.min.js)

Am I doing something wrong when I define my script(s) or is the cartodb libary not compatible with RequireJS?

I have tried with and without a shim in my requirejs build config but I always get the same error.

Issue raised [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/1465) but I am half expecting them to say it is a RequireJS issue rather than a CartoDb issue.

Answer (score -2):

Try to add param cartodb to use it in function body, like this:

```
define('app', ['module', 'jquery', 'cartodb'],
function(m, $, cartodb) { 
  ...
```